# $n$th root of unity - why does polynomial $x^n-1$ factor as $(x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)\cdots(x-\zeta^{n-1})$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> $n$th root of unity -
>    why does polynomial $x^n-1$ factor as $$(x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)\cdots(x-\zeta^{n-1})?$$

I am specifically working on the case of the $7$th root of unity.  I know that $x^7-1$ will have $7$ distinct roots,$(x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)\cdots(x-\zeta^6)$.  Also, that $x^7=1$ roots are primitive roots of order $7$ in the multiplicative group of their field, $F$.

But, I am having trouble explaining why it factors as it does in more detail.

I would appreciate a more detailed and clearer understanding as to why $x^7-1$ factors as it does in a field, $F$.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ K $ be a field, then any polynomial in $ K[x] $ splits as the product of linear factors over some larger field $ L \supset K $. This means that we can assume that the roots of our polynomial are in $ K $ without loss of generality.

Let $ P(x) \in K[x] $ be a polynomial with $ \deg P = n $ with $ n $ distinct roots $ \mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n $ in $ K $. Since $ K[x] $ is Euclidean, we have $ (x-\mu_k) | P(x) $ for any $ \mu_k $, and since these factors are pairwise coprime it follows that $ (x-\mu_1)(x-\mu_2)\ldots(x-\mu_n) | P(x) $. Write

$$ P(x) = (x-\mu_1)(x-\mu_2)\ldots(x-\mu_n) Q(x) $$

Now, taking degrees, we find that $ \deg P = n + \deg Q $, hence $ \deg Q = 0 $ and $ Q $ is a constant polynomial, i.e it is an element of the ground field $ K $. Hence we may write

$$ P(x) = a (x-\mu_1)(x-\mu_2)\ldots(x-\mu_n) $$

where $ a \in K $. In particular, if $ P(x) $ is monic then $ a = 1 $. Now, simply let the $ \mu_k $ be the seventh roots of unity, and let $ P(x) = x^7 - 1 $ to obtain the result.

Answer (score 2):

If $\zeta^n=1$, then $\zeta^0=1, \zeta, \zeta^2, \dots \zeta^{n-1}$ are roots of $x^n-1$.

If $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-root, then these roots are all different.

Therefore, $x^n-1$ and $(x-1)(x-\zeta)\cdots(x-\zeta^{n-1})$ are two monic polynomials of the same degree and with the same roots and so they must be equal.

Comment: Thank you. To be sure I understand clearly we have that ζ, ζ^2,... , ζ^(n-1) are each equal to 1 which is what nth roots of unity implies. Then, these distinct roots result in the LHS=0 and the factors of the RHS, with these roots, will each equal to zero as well.  Is this correct?